# Parsing CSS background-image 2015

Tags: javascript, css, regex, background-image

I am looking for an updated answer to this question [Parsing CSS background-image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6970221/parsing-css-background-image)

The answer there seems to get things right but unfortunately it strips out the percentage values on stop points in gradients (see my comment there for an example)

So what I am hoping someone could help me with is an updated regex like joos accepted answer that doesn't strip percentage stop point values from gradients...

Or maybe there is another way?

Comment: I don't think CSS `background-image` property values meet the criteria for a Regular Language and so cannot be successfully (reliably and robustly) parsed with a Regular Expression.

Comment: actually looking at it, all I need I think is to split the property on any comma that is not inside brackets, all I need is an array of the background images...

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have done this which seems to work ok- probably dont need to use jQuery but I'll post an update...

```
splitBgImage : function(string) {
        //split the background-image string into an array of characters
        //iterate over the array of characters adding each to the bgimg variable
        //if we encounter a ( then we increment brackets by one
        //if we encounter a ) then we decrement brackets by one
        //if we encounter a , then if brackets == 0 then we push the bgimg property to the bgimgs array and set the bgimg property back to ''
        //if we are at the end of the array add whats left to bgimgs minus the ';'
        var brackets = 0, bgimg = '', bgimgs = [], splitString = string.split(''), totalLength = jQuery(splitString).length;
        jQuery.each(splitString, function(index, char){
            if(char == '(')
                {
                brackets ++;
                }
            if(char == ')')
                {
                brackets -- ;
                }
            if(char == ',' && brackets == 0)
                {
                bgimgs.push(bgimg);
                bgimg = ''; 
                }
            else
                {
                if(char != ';')
                bgimg += char;  
                }
            if(index == totalLength-1)
                {
                bgimgs.push(bgimg); 
                }
        });
        return bgimgs;
    }
```