# Split background-image property string given in CSS

Tags: javascript, css, arrays

I have a CSS property of `background-image` with this value.

```
background-image: url("https://someURLgoeshere/someImageName.jpg\"),linear-gradient(to bottom, hsla(110, 100.00%, 50.00%, 1.00),hsla(110, 100.00%, 50.00%, 1.00)), radial-gradient(to bottom, hsla(251, 100.00%, 50.00%, 0.86),hsla(251, 100.00%, 50.00%, 0.86));
```

From the above given value string I want to split each background-image differently.
I want the output something like below.

```
const someArray = [url("https://someURLgoeshere/someImageName.jpg\"), linear-gradient(to bottom, hsla(110, 100.00%, 50.00%, 1.00),hsla(110, 100.00%, 50.00%, 1.00)), radial-gradient(to bottom, hsla(251, 100.00%, 50.00%, 0.86),hsla(251, 100.00%, 50.00%, 0.86)) ]
```

In short I want to split the value and store it in string Index wise.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Try splitting on `[)"]\)+,\s*` see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/nWIV1Q/1/)

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6970221/parsing-css-background-image
This has the answer for my question.