# Is there a simple string parser for Python?

Tags: python, string, parsing

I have a string like that: `'aaa(cc(kkk)c)ddd[lll]{m(aa)mm}'`. From that string I want to get the following structure: `['aaa', '(cc(kkk)c)', 'ddd', '[lll]', '{m(aa)mm}']`. In other words I would like to separate substrings that are in brackets of different types.

Comment: Why did your `(cc(kkk)c)` structure change to `(cc{kkk}c)`?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. it should be (cc(kkk)c).

Comment: Right, so your parenthesis and brackets can be nested.

Comment: Similar question: [Python parsing bracketed blocks](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1651487/222914)

Comment: @JanneKarila: That question only has to deal with *one* type of bracket. When you have more than one a stack approach is the only way to deal with matching openers with closers properly.

Comment: @MartijnPieters OP did not specify how to deal with mismatched parenthesis. I agree with your answer; it is the sane approach, and it requires a stack, but the requested output from the example could be produced in a simpler way too.

Comment: @JanneKarila: Sure, that specific example can be produced with a simple counter, but it's a sure bet the OP will come back with a 'but what about the `aa{bb)cc` case where the brackets do not match?' example. :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use a stack approach to track nesting levels:

```
pairs = {'{': '}', '[': ']', '(': ')'}

def parse_groups(string):
    stack = []
    last = 0
    for i, c in enumerate(string):
        if c in pairs:
            # push onto the stack when we find an opener
            if not stack and last < i:
                # yield anything *not* grouped
                yield string[last:i]
            stack.append((c, i))
        elif c in pairs:
            if stack and pairs[stack[-1][0]] == c:
                # Found a closing bracket, pop the stack
                start = stack.pop()[1]
                if not stack:
                    # Group fully closed, yield
                    yield string[start:i + 1]
                    last = i + 1
            else:
                raise ValueError('Missing opening parethesis')

    if stack:
        raise ValueError('Missing closing parethesis')

    if last < len(string):
        # yield the tail
        yield string[last:]
```

This will generate groups, cast to a list if you need one:

```
>>> list(parse_groups('aaa(cc(kkk)c)ddd[lll]{m(aa)mm}'))
['aaa', '(cc(kkk)c)', 'ddd', '[lll]', '{m(aa)mm}']
```

If the brackets / parenthesis do not balance, an exception is raised:

```
>>> list(parse_groups('aa(bb'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 19, in parse_groups
ValueError: Missing closing parethesis
>>> list(parse_groups('aa[{bb}}'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 20, in parse_groups
ValueError: Missing opening parethesis
>>> list(parse_groups('aa)bb'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 20, in parse_groups
ValueError: Missing opening parethesis
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also look at [pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/Documentation). Interestingly, this can be implemented as a stack, where you can push string fragments when you find {[( and pop when you find )]}.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try [**Custom String Parser**](https://github.com/dotpot/Custom-String-Parser) library (I'm the author of it). It's designed to work with data which has any logical structure, so you can customize it the way you want ;)

Comment: Please do disclose explicitly that you are linking to your own project; see the [FAQ#promotion]. It's fine, but it is quickly seen as spam instead of helping the OP otherwise. :-)

Comment: Shouldnt I recommend a library (even I'm the author) if it you can solve your problem ?

Comment: You can recommend a library, but if it is *your* project, say so. :-)