# Parsing program input string for math expression

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, parsing, math

I'm trying to program a `worlfram alpha` like math expression solver. 
My current obstacle is figuring out which opening and closing brackets are corresponding.

For example, how would I figure out which brackets in `((1 * 3) / (4 / 2))` are matching. The program will solve each of these sections individually, and when doing so replacing the section in the original with the answer.

So, for example, the first section the program would try to solve in `((1 * 3) / (4 / 2))` would be `(1 * 3)`, so it would replace that section with the product, 3, and `((1 * 3) / (4 / 2))` would now be `(3 / (4 / 2))`.

My current code, if helpful is here - http://pastebin.com/Xpayzbff, the function that is handling the paring is `parse()`.

Thanks!

Edit (7/3/2019):
For anyone attempting a similar project, I did eventually figure this out soon after asking. For the purpose of being helpful, here is my source code - https://github.com/j-osephlong/python-arithmetic

Comment: As I say [in my profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2617068/tigerhawkt3?tab=profile), calculators are not the best choice for a beginner coding project. You might consider programming something like a card game or board game instead.

Comment: To implement an infix expression evaluator (not a solver, because solver is something else), you need to understand and use recursion.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 or at least a single operation one with three separate args

Comment: Please do not use PasteBin. Make your questions self contained, and a [mcve] of what you wish to accomplish

Comment: @DYZ Didn't realize  pastebin was poor choice, but in the code I have so far I do use recursion, but the way it selects a section doesn't work for all expressions

Comment: @TigerhawkT3, I understand what you're saying but this isn't a beginner project for me, I've programmed for a good while now and understand python primarily a good bit,  just thought this would be a cool project

Comment: @cricket_007 should I resubmit with a fix?

Comment: You're welcome to [edit] your question at any time

Answer (score 0):

I'm not gonna write code for you, because that would defeat the point, but what you probably want is the [Shunting-yard algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm). It converts from infix (how humans normally represent series of operations, with the operator *in* the operands) into postfix(which is easy for a computer to evaluate, with the operator *after* the operands).

Here is someone who did it for boolean login in python: https://msoulier.wordpress.com/2009/08/01/dijkstras-shunting-yard-algorithm-in-python/

You could also try parsing the statement directly into an [AST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree), which you could then manipulate.

Also make sure to check out the [tokenizer module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tokenize.html) for python.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Shunting-Yard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) algorithm. However, a complete implementation of the algorithm is pretty involved. Here is simpler, somewhat naive version that could give you a basic understanding https://gist.github.com/tiabas/339f5c06f541c176a02c02cc3113d6f7

```
# Simple Shunting-Yard solution
#
# Given a math expression, parse and evaluate
# the expression
#
# E.g '2+1' => 3, 8/2*4+1 => 17, 2+(1*2) = 4, ((2+4)/2*7) => 21
# 
def parse_math_expression(exp):
    PRECENDENCE = {
        ')': 3,
        '(': 3,
        '*': 1,
        '/': 1,
        '+': 0,
        '-': 0,
    }
    output = []
    operators = []
    for ch in exp:
        # Handle nested expressions
        if ch == ')':
            opr = operators.pop(0)
            while opr != '(':
                output.append(opr)
                opr = operators.pop(0)
        elif ch.isdigit():
            output.append(ch)
        else:
            # Handle operator prescendence
            top_op = None
            if len(operators) and operators[0]:
                top_op = operators[0]
            # Check if top operator has greater prcendencethan current char
            if top_op in ['*', '/'] and PRECENDENCE[top_op] > PRECENDENCE[ch]:
                output.append(top_op)
                operators.pop(0)
            # Push operator onto queues
            operators.insert(0, ch)
    # Handle any leftover operators
    while len(operators):
        output.append(operators.pop(0))
    return output

test1 = "(2+1)"
assert parse_math_expression(test1) == ['2', '1', '+']
test2 = "((2+4)/(2*7))"
assert parse_math_expression(test2) == ['2', '4', '+', '2', '7', '*', '/']
test3 = "(3*2)+(4/2)"
assert parse_math_expression(test3) == ['3', '2', '*','4', '2', '/','+']

def eval_parsed_expression(exp):
    OPRS = {
        '+': lambda a, b: a + b,
        '-': lambda a, b: a - b,
        '*': lambda a, b: a * b,
        '/': lambda a, b: a / b
    }
    tmp = []
    while len(exp) > 1:
        k = exp.pop(0)
        while not k in ['*', '-', '+', '/']:
            tmp.insert(0, k)
            k = exp.pop(0)
        o = k
        b = tmp.pop(0)
        a = tmp.pop(0)
        r = OPRS[o](int(a), int(b))
        exp.insert(0, r)
    return exp[0]

test4 = ['2', '1', '+'] # (2+1*2)
assert eval_parsed_expression(test4) == 3
test5 = ['2', '1', '2', '*', '+'] # (2+1*2)
assert eval_parsed_expression(test5) == 4
test6 = ['3', '2', '*','4', '2', '/','+'] # (3*2)+(4/2)
assert eval_parsed_expression(test6) == 8
```

Answer (score -1):

Treat an expression between brackets as a list of symbols which can also contain another list. So `"((1 * 3) / (4 / 2))"` is represented by `[['1', '*', '3'], '/', ['4', '/' '2']]`. Call a list of symbols a ‘node’.

As you iterate the string, maintain a stack, which keeps track of the ‘bracket pair’ (or node) that you’re in. Append symbols to the last node in the stack (`current_node`). At each `'('`, add a new node to the node you’re in, *and* to the stack. At each `')'`, pop the stack, so that you’re in the parent node, and further symbols will be appended there.

Then you can recursively evaluate each node, inside first, until you have a final value.

Reverse engineer this code.

```
def parse(expr):
    stack = [[]]
    for i in expr:
        current_node = stack[-1]
        if i == '(':
            new_node = []
            current_node.append(new_node)
            stack.append(new_node)
        elif i == ')':
            stack.pop()
        elif not i.isspace():
            current_node.append(i)

    return stack[0]

print(parse('(1 * 3) / (4 / 2)')) # [['1', '*', '3'], '/', ['4', '/', '2']]
```

---

Check out this question:
[Python parsing bracketed blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1651487/python-parsing-bracketed-blocks)