# Pulling out certain strings from split method

Tags: python, string, methods, split

I would like my output to be only words in parentheses inside the string without using regex.

Code:

```
def parentheses(s):
    return s.split()

print(parentheses("Inside a (space?)")) 
print(parentheses("To see (here) but color")) 
print(parentheses("Very ( good (code"))
```

Output:

```
['Inside', 'a', '(space?)'] -> **space?**
['To', 'see', '(here)', 'but', 'color'] -> **here**
['Very', '(', 'good', '(code'] -> **empty**
```

Comment: Use a list comprehension that checks whether the word is in parentheses.

Comment: `if word.startswith('(') and word.endswith(')')`

Comment: There are some options here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1651487/706456

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an old fashioned way of doing it with a loop and referencing the ends with a dictionary.

```
def parentheses(s):
    ends = {"(":[],")":[]}
    for i, char in enumerate(s):
        if char in ["(", ")"]:
            ends[char].append(i)
    if not ends["("] or not ends[")"]:
        return ""
    return s[min(ends["("]) + 1: max(ends[")"])]


print(parentheses("Inside a (space?)"))
print(parentheses("To see (here) but color"))
print(parentheses("Very ( good (code"))
```

OUTPUT:

```
space?
here
```

If you must use `str.split`  this will work as well.

```
def parentheses(s):
    parts = s.split("(")
    if len(parts) > 1:
        s = "(".join(parts[1:])
        parts = s.split(")")
        if len(parts) > 1:
            return ")".join(parts[:-1])
    return ""
```

Comment: @cnsc.bot  I just added a version that uses str.split like your question asks.

Comment: @cns.bot Please remember to mark the questions as answered